# GCM onMessageReceived() not called on specific (or some) devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using **Google Cloud Messaging** to implement push notification in my android application.
Everything works great on most devices, but when I test the app on a **Samsung Galaxy S Dous GT-S7562 (Android 4.0.4, API 15)** , when I send a notification, it doesn't call **onMessageReceived()** method.

As **everything works properly on other devices**, I'm pretty sure about the functionality of my code.
I check the availability of **GooglePlayServices** with the code below and it returns **true** :

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Although the **RegistrationIntentService()** sends the token of the device to my server and also GCM call from my server responses "**success**", the app doesn't call **onMessageRecieved()** method as I put log at the beginning of it.

Is there anything else that I have to check to debug the problem?

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's happening for me too with FCM.

Answer (score 0):

Check your script if it contains notification in payload

see the below link

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: I use data and manage it myself : 
{"registration_ids":[" ... mytoken ... "],"data":{"type":"mynotification","title":"1","message":"2"}}

Comment: I've tried this too, but no luck :
{"registration_ids":[" ...mytoken ... "],"data":{"title":"1","2":"message","type":"mynotification"},"notification" : { "body" : "great match!","title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark", "icon" : "myicon"}}

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific case. First, it’s needed to check the registration token following this link. 
Check to registration token by curl : See this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http).

```
# api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
   --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
   https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
   -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

“If you want to confirm the validity of a registration token, you can do so by replacing "ABC" with the registration token.”

I thought that it’s better to investigate after checking the result of curl.
You can refer to this [site](https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/notifications-d7df385b0ff4#.d0qukktl9) too.

Additional, it may be better to check the notification setting of the device.

I hope this helps.